# What are the technical differences between writing a Node.js module using Neon vs Wasm?

Tags: rust, webassembly

I wish to write a npm module for node.js, using Rust. After some quick research, I found two ways to do it:

- [Neon](https://github.com/neon-bindings/neon): "Rust bindings for writing safe and fast native Node.js modules"
- [Wasm](https://www.rust-lang.org/what/wasm): "Binary instruction format for a stack-based virtual machine."

What are the technical differences of using one or the other?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Neon provides bindings, making it easy to write native node modules in Rust. Native node modules, as the name implies, are compiled to native code (typically on installation).

Wasm (WebAssembly) is a new runtime for the browser, and node, that is designed to be a fast and efficient compilation target for a wider range of languages. It is executed alongside the JavaScript runtime, sharing threads / memory. Rust has very good WebAssembly support and bindings.

So the main difference is Neon compiles to native, while with wasm you are compiling to a new runtime (that has near native performance).

WebAssembly potentially reduces some of the friction involved in using native node modules.

Comment: Do you know if there is a difference in terms of performance?

Comment: @slorenzo that would depend on your use-case, but i would expect native to be somewhat faster than wasm, but both to be many times faster than JS

Comment: There is some research that SSVM can outperform native in some cases: https://www.infoq.com/articles/arm-vs-x86-cloud-performance